# Can cantor pairing function prove that 2D Turing Machine can be represented by 1-tape TM?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I'm trying to figure out if a 2-Dimensional Turing Machine can be represented by any 1-tape TM. I came across the [Cantor Pairing Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) when doing some research. And based on my understanding and how the pairing function works, any 2D TM can be represented by a 1-tape TM if it uses that said function.

Am I right? Can someone elaborate a little bit more on that please.

Comment: That's unfortunately not enough, though it's a good first step. Try to write a complete proof.

Comment: Am I going in the right direction? The cantor pairing function can prove that right?

Comment: You need to use a pairing function to represent the 2D tape on the 1D tape, but that's not the complete proof. I suggest trying to write a complete proof. That's the only way to see what, if anything, is missing.

Comment: The way I would prove it would be by giving an actual example of a 2D TM (grid of numbers for example) and by using the function, be able to map it on a 1-Tape TM.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not your TA, so I won't answer any further questions.

Comment: How is your 2D TM defined?